# MySQL Select parents and childs in proper order with single query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I have a MySQL table with following data:

```
ID Name      ParentID
1  Foo       null
2  Bar       null
3  Foo SubA  1
4  Bar SubA  2
5  Foo SubC  1
6  Foo SubB  1
```

I would like to retreive all data with following order:

```
1  Foo       null
3  Foo SubA  1
6  Foo SubB  1
5  Foo SubC  1
2  Bar       null
4  Bar SubA  2
```

Is it possible with MySQL and single query?

Comment: MySQL prior to version 8.0 didn't support recursive functions, so wasn't well-suited to this "adjacency list" model of storing hierarchical data—the "nested sets" or "closure table" models were preferred instead.  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Is this multi-level, i.e. can a parent record itself have a parent record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a two-level hierarchie, i.e. no grandparents and grandchildren, it's a mere `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select id, name, parentid
from mytable
order by coalesce(parentid, id), parentid is not null, name;
```

This makes use of MySQL's true = 1, false = 0. `parentid is not null` is 0 for the parent and 1 for the children.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursive CTE (MySQL 8.0+):

```
-- 2 level hierarchy (parent-child)
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
   SELECT tx.*, 1 AS lvl, ID AS grp FROM tx WHERE ParentID IS NULL
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT tx.*, lvl+1, cte.ID FROM tx JOIN cte WHERE tx.ParentId = cte.Id
)
SELECT ID, Name, ParentId
FROM cte
ORDER BY grp, lvl, Name;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/geon427HbPimphcLxyqs5/0)**

Comment: All is qood except that I've forgotten to mention that I have MySQL 5.6